# How to schedule VMs in few specific host?

Tags: openstack, scheduling, openstack-nova

I have 4 nodes, 1 controller nodes and 3 compute node.

I divined into 2 AZ, AZ1 (compute1) and AZ2(compute2, compute3)

I can use create instance w/ `--avaibilty-zone AZ1 (AZ2)` to make the instance build in compute1 or compute2/3

But the openstack always schedule VMs on compute3 why I set `--avability-zone AZ2` (3 compute nodes have like the same config (8GB ram, 4 core, HDD).

So are there anyway to make openstack schedule VMs on compute2 node too when I use `--avaibility-zone AZ2`

I only can use `--avaibilty-zone AZ2:compute2:compute2` to make the instance create on it.

Answer (score 1):

Nova scheduler will decide which compute node based on the resource usage & availability. Maybe you can enable the debug mode in nova.conf to get more detail for the scheduler decision.

Possibly also check your AZ definition like this and make sure two nodes (compute2 & compute3) are available and enabled.
`openstack availability zone list --long --compute`

--availability-zone AZ2:compute2 will bypass nova-scheduler and assign the compute node directly. It will work but not the best way to do it.